# Extract text and put into table

Tags: r, string

As result of the checkresiduals() function from the forecast package and rbind() function I got this matrix (ETS_RESIDUALS):

```
#Result of checkresiduals() function

     [,1]                                         
[1,] "Q* = 161.83, df = 18.8, p-value < 2.2e-16"  
[2,] "Q* = 125.46, df = 18.8, p-value < 2.2e-16"  
[3,] "Q* = 263.65, df = 18.8, p-value < 2.2e-16"  
[4,] "Q* = 81.503, df = 18.8, p-value = 8.763e-10"
[5,] "Q* = 36.616, df = 18.8, p-value = 0.008178" 

str(ETS_RESIDUALS)
#chr [1:5, 1] "Q* = 161.83, df = 18.8, p-value < 2.2e-16" "Q* = 125.46, df = 18.8, p-value < 2.2e-16" "Q* = 263.65, df = 18.8, p-value < 2.2e-16" ...

class(ETS_RESIDUALS)
#[1] "matrix"
```

Now, my intention is to split this lines of text with grep() or other functions into a data.frame (with four columns TEST, Q*, df, p-value), like in the example below:

```
TEST      Q*        df        p-value
--------------------------------------------
TEST_1  161.83     18.8        2.2e-16  
TEST_2  125.46     18.8        2.2e-16  
TEST_3  263.65     18.8        2.2e-16  
TEST_4  81.503     18.8        8.763e-10
TEST_5  36.616     18.8        0.008178
```

I try with this lines of code but results are not good.

```
ETS_RESIDUALS %>%   
  stringr::str_replace_all("(\\S+) =", "`\\1` =") %>%   
  paste0("data.frame(", ., ", check.names = FALSE)")
```

Can anyone help me with this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
#separate based on ,
separate(data.frame(mat), mat ,into = c('Q*','df','p-value'),sep = ',') %>% 
mutate_all(~str_extract(.,'(?<=\\=|\\<\\s).*')) %>% 
#Use positive look-behind to extract everything after = or < followed by a space
mutate(TEST=paste0('TEST_',1:n())) %>% select(TEST,everything())

    TEST      Q*    df    p-value
1 TEST_1  161.83  18.8    2.2e-16
2 TEST_2  125.46  18.8    2.2e-16
3 TEST_3  263.65  18.8    2.2e-16
4 TEST_4  81.503  18.8  8.763e-10
5 TEST_5  36.616  18.8   0.008178
```

Data

```
mat <- structure(c("Q* = 161.83, df = 18.8, p-value < 2.2e-16", "Q* = 125.46, df = 18.8, p-value < 2.2e-16", "Q* = 263.65, df = 18.8, 
       p-value < 2.2e-16", "Q* = 81.503, df = 18.8, p-value = 8.763e-10", "Q* = 36.616, df = 18.8, p-value = 0.008178"), 
      .Dim = c(5L, 1L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `strsplit` into an `array` then solve into a `data.frame` object.

```
A <- array(apply(M, 1, function(x) unlist(strsplit(strsplit(x, ", ")[[1]], "\\s[<=]\\s"))), 
  c(2, 3, nrow(M)))
d <- setNames(as.data.frame(t(apply(A, 3, function(x) as.numeric(x[2, ])))), A[1,,1])
```

***Yields***

```
d
#        Q*   df   p-value
# 1 161.830 18.8 2.200e-16
# 2 125.460 18.8 2.200e-16
# 3 263.650 18.8 2.200e-16
# 4  81.503 18.8 8.763e-10
# 5  36.616 18.8 8.178e-03
```

***Data***

```
M <- structure(c("Q* = 161.83, df = 18.8, p-value < 2.2e-16", "Q* = 125.46, df = 18.8, 
                 p-value < 2.2e-16", 
"Q* = 263.65, df = 18.8, p-value < 2.2e-16", "Q* = 81.503, df = 18.8, p-value = 8.763e-10", 
"Q* = 36.616, df = 18.8, p-value = 0.008178"), .Dim = c(5L, 1L
))
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to split and use logical subset.

```
v1 <- unlist(strsplit(m1, ' = | < | > |, '))
setNames(as.data.frame(matrix(v1[c(FALSE, TRUE)], nrow = nrow(m1), byrow = TRUE)), 
                                                                   unique(v1[c(TRUE, FALSE)]))
#      Q*   df p-value
#1 161.83 18.8 2.2e-16
#2 161.83 18.8 2.2e-16
#3 161.83 18.8 2.2e-16
#4 161.83 18.8 2.2e-16
#5 161.83 18.8 2.2e-16
```

To create the extra column, just

```
df$TEST <- paste0('TEST', seq(nrow(df)))
```

**NOTE:** All the values are the same because of the sample matrix having all strings the same,

```
[,1]                                       
[1,] "Q* = 161.83, df = 18.8, p-value < 2.2e-16"
[2,] "Q* = 161.83, df = 18.8, p-value < 2.2e-16"
[3,] "Q* = 161.83, df = 18.8, p-value < 2.2e-16"
[4,] "Q* = 161.83, df = 18.8, p-value < 2.2e-16"
[5,] "Q* = 161.83, df = 18.8, p-value < 2.2e-16"
```

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain? I don't mind the downvote, just give an explanation so I can improve. Thank you